# How do we calculate the value of vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

I'm self-studying a course, and I'm coming across some notation I'm unfamiliar with. The following definition of what it means for a function to be differentiable is an example:

> A function $g: Z \rightarrow R^m, Z \subset R^n$ is differentiable at
>   a point $z_0$  in the interior of $Z$ if there exists a unique $m \times n$ matrix, $Dg(z_0)$, such that any given any $\epsilon > 0$,
>   there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that if $|z_0 - z| < \delta$, then
>   $|g(z) - g(z_0) - Dg(z_0)(z - z_0)| < \epsilon|z - z_0|$

First, I'm wondering how whether whether the lines on either side are meant to be referring to the absolute value of the matrices, or the determinant of the matrices. If the former, then I'd like to know how to calculate the absolute value of a matrix.

I'm having similar trouble with a statement of the Kuhn-Tucker theorem:

> If the constraint qualification holds (there exists a vector $z_0 ∈ Z$
>   such that $h(z_0) << k^*)$, $z^*$ is in the interior of $Z$ and solves the COP,
>   then there is a vector of Lagrange multipliers $q$ such that $z^*$ and
>   $q$ satisfy the Kuhn-Tucker conditions.

Again, I'm not clear what it means for one vector to be less than another, or what the double less than sign means (Wiki doesn't suggest any notational variants that would be relevant other than it being synonymous with the usual less-than sign, but I'm not sure).

Finally, I have confusion over a statement of the Lagrange necessity theorem, which states:

> Suppose that $g : Z → R, Z ⊂ R^n$ is differentiable in $z_0$ and that
>   $z_0 ∈ Z$ maximises $g$ on $Z$, then $Dg(z_0) = 0$.

Again, I'm confused about what it means for the (I'm assuming?) Jacobi matrix to here be equal to $0$. Does this mean that the sum of the partial derivatives in the matrix to be $0$, or something else?

Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: The expressions inside the vertical bars are all vectors: observe that $Dg(z_0)$ is multiplied by $z-z_0$.

Comment: And for the Lagrange Necessity Theorem, the $m \times n$ zero matrix, written just as $0$, has all of its entries equal to zero. So $Dg(z_0) = 0$ means that all of the partial derivatives are zero.

Comment: In this particular context, I think it's pretty safe to assume, without further background, that the vertical bars represent the norm of the $n$ vector $z-z_0$. The same would apply to the $m$ vector $g(z) - g(z_0) - Dg(z_0)(z-z_0)$. By the norm, I'm referring to the function $|| \cdot || : \mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $$||z|| = \sqrt{z_{1}^2 + \ldots + z_{n}^2}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone! I'm still confused about what it means to say a vector is less than another, though.

Comment: They didn't say a vector is less than another anywhere. They always were comparing numerical quantities. This is because the inequalities involved things that are the **norm** of a vector, and remember, a norm of a vector is a real number (not a vector).